# Repeat bar lines in early music

Tags: notation, repeats

I am looking for explanations on how to interpret the repeat bar lines used during the 17th century and specifically for German music. The sign ':||:' seems to be employed at that time for repeating the music section between two identically signs. But should I also play twice the section before the first sign, since the beginning of the piece?

If someone has a reference on how these bar lines were interpreted, it would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the music looks like this:

|| A :||: B :||

This should be played: A, A, B, B.

Comment: Thanks Alex for this quick answer. And if the music looks like to : 
A :||: B :||: C ||, is it A, A, B, B, C, C ?

Comment: @RémyClaverie This is poorly notated.  At the beginning of C you suggest a repeated section, then at the end of C it isn't written as such.  I suspect you mean || A :||: B :||: C :|| -- in which case it is played as AABBCC.

Comment: thanks Andrew for your answer but I did not make a mistake. It is exactly A :||: B :||: C ||. See [this sonata](https://www2.musik.uu.se/duben/presentationSource1.php?Select_Dnr=2124) from Paul Hainlein.

Comment: @RémyClaverie it's quite standard to omit the "repeat the following" sign at the beginning of a piece, which is what your question is explicitly about.  In your comment, you note something that is not at all common (I don't recall having seen it before), which is having a section that begins with a "repeat the following" sign but ends without a "repeat the preceding" sign .  Perhaps you should edit your question to ask about that instead of, or in addition to, what it now asks.

Comment: @RémyClaverie for what it's worth, I've found a similar score, but it has a bit of textual instruction as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwnpUlA_9i8

Comment: I’m with phoog: ... and please add the link of the sonata to the bottom of the question.

Comment: I looked at the organo and violin 1 parts, and after the last double bar sign there is a time signature (I think), and 5 long slow notes followed by a squiggle which probably means the end. I would not expect this last bar to be repeated, but the section before maybe. I think the notation is ambiguous, but perhaps the composer's contemporaries knew what to do in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat barlines come in pairs.   You repeat from the backwards-facing dots to the preceding forward-facing ones.   The only exception is for the first instance in a piece of music, when the forward-facing one may be omitted.    Omitting one at the end of a piece is an error.

This syntax isn't exclusive to 17th century German music.

The rules are sometimes bent a little. Notoriously so in the orchestra parts of Strauss waltzes, which can be a labyrinth of non-standard nested DS and repeat bar notations.   It saves a lot of paper, but it's VERY easy to get lost.

Answer (score -1):

`:||` - Go back till you see a `||:`, if you don't see any go to start.

So if there's a barline where you need both`:||` denoting you have to repeat previous section and `||:` saying you have to come till here in the next repeat, then,

`:|| + ||: = :||:`

It's very confusing when in second or later sections, there is a `:||` but no `||:` which means you'll go to start and that's why "Go to Start" has a seperate notion, instead of using `:||`. Its `D.C` - Da Capo - Go from Start